# Computing the variance of a PDF

Tags: probability-or-statistics, output-formatting, output

Inspired by [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133557) I try to find to compute the variance of:
$$f(\vec{t}) = \cases{\frac{d + 2}{2 c_d}(1 - \vec{t} \cdot \vec{t}) & if $\vec{t} \cdot \vec{t}< 1$ \\0 & otherwise}$$

where $c_d$ is the volume of the unit sphere of dimension $d$:

$$ c_d = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2} + 1\right)},$$
according to:
$$E[x] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x) \; dx$$
and 
$$VAR[x]= E[x^2] - \left(E[x]\right)^2.$$

I tried to do this with [the following mathematica code](https://gist.github.com/lauraBaakman/814ef4549b6acf00bc1a6b968f557c8d)

```
$Assumptions = {d >= 1, Element[d, Integers], Element[x, Vectors[d]]};
unitSphereVolume  = pi^(d/2)/Gamma[d/2 + 1];

epan [t_] = Piecewise[{{(d + 2)/(2 * unitSphereVolume) (1 - Dot[t, t]), Dot[t, t] < 1}}, 0];

EV[_t] = Refine[D[t * epan[t], t], Element[t, Vectors[d]]];
V[_t] = Refine[EV[t^2] - (EV[t])^2, Element[t, Vectors[d]]];
FunctionExpand[V[x]]
```

I want to compute the variance of $f(x)$ as a function of $d$, but evaluating this notebooks gives `V[x]` as output. What am I missing?

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `[_t]` to `[t_]`, `pi` to `Pi`

```
$Assumptions = {d >= 1, Element[d, Integers], Element[x, Vectors[d]]};
unitSphereVolume = Pi^(d/2)/Gamma[d/2 + 1];

epan[t_] = 
  Piecewise[{{(d + 2)/(2*unitSphereVolume) (1 - Dot[t, t]), 
     Dot[t, t] < 1}}, 0];

EV[t_] = Refine[D[t*epan[t], t], Element[t, Vectors[d]]];
V[t_] = Refine[EV[t^2] - (EV[t])^2, Element[t, Vectors[d]]];

FullSimplify@PiecewiseExpand@V[x]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]